# Override id creation in Azure cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a JSON document, which I need to push to azure cosmos db. I am using DocumentDB data migration tool to dump my json file to azure cosmos DB. The problem is my JSON contains an id field which is same for all the records. For e,g.

`"angularAcceleration_T12_x:-0.137993,"id":"5946001","jointAngle_jRightHip_z"`

And because of this **id** field, I am not able to insert more than 1 record in my collection as after inserting one record I get an error message "resource with specified id already exist". 
Is there a way to force cosmos DB to ignore the id field in JSON and create a GUID for each entry, like it does if it does not find an id field.

Thanks,
Yaju

Answer (score 16):

After a lot of searching i came to the verdict that if you have a column named "id"(case sensitive) in your json, cosmos db will be make that column value as the id for the document, you can not use any other column as the unique identifier.
If cosmos does not find id field, it will create a GUID as the id for the document.

Comment: The fact that this "feature" is case sensitive is a bug in my opinion.  If you want the document level id in your object, which I do so I can perform lookups and updates, the field needs to be "id" not "Id".  This is ridiculous

Answer (score 9):

[Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Resource.Id documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource.id?view=azure-dotnet) hints that it is serialised in JSON with fixed name `"id"`:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
public virtual string Id { get; set; }
```

So, I would say that **you cannot use another property as storage PK**.

What you CAN do, is convert your JSON document yourself, for example renaming your current `id` to `originalId` or similar. Then documentDB would generate unique ids on import for you.

Comment: thanks @imre pihvel, i also changed the name of id field to something else as the last resort.

Comment: For posterity, I found that this did not work with CosmosDB when using JsonPropertyName("propName") from System.Text.Json.  I had to use Newtonsoft JsonProperty as described in your answer.